# Read similar tables from multiple MySQL databases using WS02

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We got an application wherein multi-tenancy is implemented by having a unique database (MYSQL) for each tenant.  The table structures are the same.  I got a requirement to list all expiring products for each of the tenants, and I was wondering how can I incorporate all those in one data web service in WSO2?  I know that I can create a query with the database prefixing the table:
eg. select DB1.products.id, DB1.products.name from DB1.products

Do I need to define a data source for each database (100+ tenants), and can I specify the database name as an input variable in the data service operation? ie. select ?.products.id, ?.products.name from ?.products

Thank you for your help.
Cheers,
Erwin

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to have a generic data service that would retrieve those tenant specific information from those database dedicated to each tenant, as I see, the most cleanest way to achieve this would be by generifying your SQL queries and making the used datasource dynamically discoverable.

Since you're using 100+ tenants(WOW that's a huge number :)) obviously you might be having 100+ databases created for those tenants too. So, you would need to create a carbon datasource with the same name in each tenant (let's say "testDS") wrapping the tenant specific database configurations such as JDBC URL, credentials, etc. Next, if you've come up with your dataservice configuring the used datasource to be the aforementioned datasource, at runtime, it would correctly pick up the appropriate tenant specific datasource as the datasource feature completely supports multi tenancy. That would prevent you from passing the database name, etc to the SQL query and make your data service configuration more clean, generic thereby making it more maintainable.